# Does there exist an infinite number of open intervals that cover $[0,1]$ but for a finite number of intervals it does not cover $[0,1]$?

Tags: general-topology

Can you find an infinite set of open intervals such that there union contains $[0,1]$, but a finite number of such intervals does not contain $I=[0,1]$?

My thought is to invoke compactness in some way: $I$ is compact, so for an infinite cover, there is a finite subcover; then take away a few of those open sets and it doesn't cover $I$. Of course, this misses the fact that the finite number in the problem is arbitrary, so this wouldn't prove the problem above. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your objection to using compactness? What do you mean that "the finite number is arbitrary"?

Comment: You need to be more precise with the quantifiers. Is the question "does there exist an infinite open cover with a non-covering finite subcollection" or is it "does there exist an infinite open cover such that *no* finite subcollection is a cover"? My instinct says that the question is actually the latter, in which case invoking compactness is correct.

Comment: You're very confused about the logic of something. Reading the question I assume that either you'd don't know the definition of compactness in terms of open covers, or you don't know that $[0,1]$ is compact. But then your comments make it clear that you do know both those things. This raises the question "huh??". The interval is compact. So if the union of an infinite number of intervals contains $[01]$ then the union of some finite number of them also contains $[0,1]$. Maybe you didn't really ask what you meant to ask?

Comment: By the finite number being arbitrary, I mean to say that any arbitrary finite subcollection does not cover the interval I. My objection to using compactness is that it shows that I can find a finite collection that covers the interval I, while I'm trying to show there does not exist such a subcollection.

Comment: Actually upon further thought, I think I could just use compactness to disprove the statement as I did above haha. Thanks!

Comment: @Jack, We can 'pathologically' endow $\mathbb{R}$ with another topology to make the assertion tenable. If you look at $\mathbb{R}$ under the countable complement topology, then $[0,1]$ is not compact, as it is not countable, but we can cover it with a countably infinite number of sets...